# PHP - Set Session Directory For Multiple Logins?

Tags: php, session

I have a login system for /site, and /site/site-admin. My issue as of now is if I sign in on /site, /site/site-admin thinks you signed in as an admin (obviously an issue lol) I can't find any information on how to set the session only allowed to a directory, I've only found where to store the session data.

Comment: _"I've only found where to store the session data"_: Same place (whatever that may be).

Comment: @geomagas You're referring to `session_save_path ([ string $path ] )` ?

Comment: No, I'm referring to `$_SESSION` itself.

Comment: But my question is, how do I lock the $_SESSION data for /site to /site only, and /site/site-admin's respectively.

Comment: You simply don't need to. You're falling into a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. `dir_I_logged_into` is a session pareameter, isn't it?

Comment: @geomagas I understand, but then explain why I log into /site, and I gain direct access into /site/site-admin with the `$_SESSION` data from /site.

Comment: Because, apparently, the code that runs under `/site/site-admin` is not aware of the parameter. Think "`if($TheSessionRefersToA/siteLogin) { refuse_admin_access(); }`".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using [session_name()](https://www.php.net/session_name) to create two different sessions for /site and /site/site-admin?

Simply call `session_name("<sitename>")` before you open your site session, and `session_name("<sitename>-admin")` before you open your session in the admin panel. Then you have two different session-cookies, session-ids and session-data for your two sites.

*Edit:*

If you need to share session data between /site and /site/site-admin, you might need another solution. In this case, store your data in `$_SESSION['site']` instead of `$_SESSION` (or `$_SESSION['site-admin']` resp.). For example: `$_SESSION['site']['logged_in'] = true;`

In this case, both sites share the same session, but do not access the same session data. Common data can be stored in any other array key (`$_SESSION['common']` for example). But be aware: In this case the pure existance of a session does not mean that you are logged in or authorized.

Comment: How about common session data?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need to store data in your session that can be accessed by both /site and /site/site-admin?

Comment: Me? no, it's not my question. But the OP might. Or, most importantly, someone who bumps into this seeking a decent answer to a similar problem.

Comment: Ok. If somebody needs to share data between sessions, read my second suggested method (edited in my answer).

Comment: Much better. IMHO and just for the record, your edit should be _your original answer_, as it covers all cases in a much more consistent way. +1 nevertheless, _**but only for the second part**_.

Comment: Thank you. Solution 1 might be better if you can't / don't want to modify one of these pages (a forum for example). Setting a session name is much less change (and is supported in most configuration files of common applications), while solution 2 needs to change every use of `$_SESSION`. But if you write the code yourself, you're right, then solution 2 is much better.